# Group concatenate from multiple tables in mysql Ver 15.1

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have multiple tables with table 1 containing the primary id key. I am concatenating all tables based on the id. But this doesn't give me the desired output.

```
 Table1
id account type date
1 234w R 2020-01-01
2 567 FD 2020-05-07
3 678gh FD 2020-09-10

Table2
id designation
2 customer
3 employee
3 manager

Table3
id state
1 UP
2 AP
3 UK
```

This is what I tried

```
SELECT CONCAT(`account`,"/",`type`,"/",`date`),
GROUP_CONCAT(Table2.designation SEPARATOR "/") AS t2,
GROUP_CONCAT(Table3.state SEPARATOR "/") AS t3,
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 ON t1.id=t2.id
LEFT JOIN table1 ON t1.id=t3.id
GROUP BY t1.id

Expected output
234w/R/2020-01-01 NULL UP
567/FD/2020-05-07 CUSTOMER AP
678gh/FD/2020-09-10 EMPLOYEE/MANAGER UK
```

Comment: mysql 2.7? Are you sure?

Comment: @forpas its version 15. Thanks for pointing that out. I still had my python version in mind I guess.

Comment: Is there a reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, there may be multiple matches in both tables. In that case, I would recommend pre-aggregation. I find that it's easy to express this with subqueries:

```
select concat_ws('/', account, type, date) as res,
    (select group_concat(designation separator '/') from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id) as designations,
    (select group_concat(state       separator '/') from table3 t3 there t3.id = t1.id) as states
from table1 t1
```

Note that `concat_ws()` comes handy to shorten the first `concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must fix your joins.
Also use an aggregate function like MAX() for the 1st column, because it is not included in `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MAX(CONCAT(account,"/",type,"/",date)) AS col1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.designation SEPARATOR "/") AS col2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t3.state SEPARATOR "/") AS col3
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.id=t3.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

In the 2nd `GROUP_CONCAT()` I use `DISTINCT` because from your expected results it seems that you don't want duplicates.
You may also use it in the 1st `GROUP_CONCAT()`
.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=acefea0056736d691e40ba8ef1f3bed9).
Results:

```
> col1                         | col2             | col3
> :--------------------------- | :--------------- | :---
> 234w/R/2020-01-01 00:00:00   | null             | UP  
> 567/FD/2020-05-07 00:00:00   | customer         | AP  
> 678gh/FD/2020-09-10 00:00:00 | employee/manager | UK
```